# Div inside another div with transparent padding

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with the following situation. It is hard for me to describe it the right way, so I have created an example in Photoshop to illustrate the situation.

Please visit the following link: http://websitedelivery.nl/files/example.png

Some explanation: I am working on a website which uses images as the website's background. Now I need to create two content areas, a large one and a smaller one that will only be shown at the top right, both containing text. The thing is that the text from the large content block needs to continue during the whole content block (partially at the top and the full width at the bottom).

Anyone got a clue how to achieve this with just HTML and CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I see many of you use a border around the top right block, but unfortunately that won't do it. It needs to show the background-image of the page. I have updated my image so that you can see what I mean: http://websitedelivery.nl/files/example1.png

Answer (score 2):

You could make a div, and make the little block inside it float to the right. The content in the parent will wrap around it.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="smallbox">smallbox with content</div>
    <p>... content ...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20px;
}
#smallbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    background: lightblue;
    float: right;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/qN4VN/)

Adjust it to your needs.

[EDIT]
Improved version, with also rounded border in the small box: [**clickerdecklick**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/qN4VN/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @linkinted, but this won't achieve it. See, the thing is, I want to have like 10 pixels of padding around the top right area (only left and bottom side), so that you see a little of the background between the two textareas, like in the example I provided. Any clues?

Comment: You're close, but I see you use a 10px border around the small box. That won't work because I need to show the background between these two areas.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... where do you want to see the background?? And what do you mean with background, the gray or the white?

Comment: @arvanderkamp else the text will stick to the side of the div, now you have a small space around the text.

Comment: @linkinted I have updated my post with another image which will hopefully make you understand

Comment: How about creating a container div for #smallbox, and re-using the same background for the container, but displace it so that it ligns up with the page background?

Comment: That is the only way Josef... but that won't work if you have a bg-image that covers the whole page or resizes with the screen.

Comment: @linkinTED Indeed, it needs to cover the whole page. Any further ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Or you should split it up in three divs... which probably isn't wishful. Or take a border-color that almost matches the background image..

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S6tSL/

Basic structure:

```
<section class="content">
    <aside>
        <div class="inner-border">Top right text...</div>
    </aside>
    The rest of the text...
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content aside {
    margin: -30px -30px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content aside .inner-border {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Hopefully that should get you started.

Comment: thanks, but that won't do it unfortunately. I need to use a background-image and not a background-color, so the border around the small box won't do it. Any other ideas?

Comment: What you're looking for is not possible, unless you're willing to a) separate the content in the large block into two separate containers (i.e. insert a predictable break somewhere), or b) use the same background image as the border for the small box and line them up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

While editing the fiddle, many other answers have been appeared, 
but I will also share my own :),

while others have also good answers, 
hope this help

http://jsfiddle.net/hY9w3/3/

Just for reference:

```
body {
    background: url(http://hdpicstock.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Beautiful-Nature-Wood-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    margin: 15px auto; /* center the wrapper*/
}

.content-top-left{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 66px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
}

.content-top-right{
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;


}

.content-top-right-inner{
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    min-height:20px;
}


.content-bottom{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}

.content-top-left, .content-bottom, .content-top-right{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content-top-left">
       Top left 
    </div>

    <div class="content-top-right">
        <div class="content-top-right-inner">
        Carentem sunt tuti tuba, Habitandae
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="content-bottom">
        bottom content
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why should you use an inner border ? p.s. (the jsfiddle isnt the same as the example u post)

Comment: Oops, you are right, I posted here the wrong code, anyway I updated my answer

Comment: @Ahmad thanks, but that won't do it unfortunately. I need to use a background-image and not a background-color, so the border around the small box won't do it. Any other ideas?

Comment: After updating the question, I updated the fiddle, check my new answer, this is the best what you can do with CSS, what is missing is the outer corner, this can be accomplished with an image

Answer (score 0):

on the basis of posted image I've made a Demo. You many CHECK the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bexevuso/1/)** FIRST.

**CSS Code is here**

```
body {background:gold;}

.container{ 
background:#ffffff; 
broder-radius:5px; 
height:auto;  
overflow:hidden;
}

.container p{ padding:4px;}

.info{
float:right; 
background:#ffffff;  
border-radius: 8px;
padding:5px;
height:120px;
border:10px solid gold;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top:0;
border-right:0;
}
```

**HTML Code is like this**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="info">smallbox with content</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vulputate placerat augue, non dictum dolor semper in. Morbi vitae magna scelerisque, cursus dolor ac, tincidunt diam. Nulla iaculis turpis non consectetur vestibulum. Maecenas in magna ligula. Curabitur ornare auctor aliquam. Vestibulum mattis, felis bibendum molestie euismod, lacus orci ornare sapien, eget suscipit urna massa eu nunc. Mauris nulla tellus, aliquam eu ornare in, euismod quis enim. Cras vel aliquet neque. Suspendisse accumsan ante at molestie rutrum. Aliquam aliquet lacus nec nisi dignissim posuere.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but that won't do it unfortunately. I need to use a background-image and not a background-color, so the border around the small box won't do it. Any other ideas?

Comment: i am looking at it right now.. will back to you as soon I got solution